# Issue with installing factory_girl_rails gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, factory-bot

I'm following a TDD tutorial by Thoughtbot, and it is great but a little bit out of date. Everything worked fine until I tried to install the factory_girl_rails v 4.0 gem and run bundle, as instructed. Factory Girl is currently at v. 4.4.0 but the workshop is specific so I am trying to keep with the versions they use when possible.

Bundler said:

```
Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: Errno::ECONNRESET: Connection reset by peer - SSL_connect (link omitted b/c SO won't let me post it)
An error occurred while installing factory_girl (4.4.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install factory_girl -v '4.4.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

So I did this:

```
gem install factory_girl_rails
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'factory_girl_rails' (>= 0), here is why:
      Unable to download data from (link omitted b/c SO won't let me post it/) - Errno::ECONNRESET: Connection reset by peer - SSL_connect (link omitted b/c SO won't let me post it)
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: factory_girl_rails
```

Tried to figure out if this was maybe just something to do with my connection. Took out the line from my gemfile & ran bundle, all fine.

After searching around discovered maybe the problem was that my version of Ruby was 1.9.3, so I updated to 2.1.2 using RVM.

Now when I run bundle I get this:

```
Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: Errno::ECONNRESET: Connection reset by peer - SSL_connect (https://rubygems.org/gems/rake-10.3.2.gem)
An error occurred while installing rake (10.3.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rake -v '10.3.2'` succeeds before bundling.
```

So I tried:

```
gem install rake -v '10.3.2'
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rake' (= 10.3.2), here is why:
      Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - Errno::ECONNRESET: Connection reset by peer - SSL_connect 
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: rake
```

same error with gem install rake

Here's my rake version:

```
rake --version
rake, version 10.1.0
```

I feel like I'm heading into the mire here and worry that I will end up making things worse if I continue to monkey around! It seems like I should back up to Ruby v. 1.9.3, but if I run

```
rvm --default use ruby-1.9
ruby-1.9.3-p547 is not installed.
```

To install do: `rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p547`

It seems like a bad idea to go backwards.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there might be an ssl problem somewhere. I'd try running `rvm osx-ssl-certs update all` in your terminal, and trying again.

Comment: I ran: rvm osx-ssl-certs update all
Updating certificates for /usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem: Already up to date.
Updating certificates for /etc/openssl/cert.pem: Already up to date.

Comment: That does seem like a good conclusion, though, as now I somehow have lost the ability to install anything with gem install or brew install. Always same error: Errno::ECONNRESET: Connection reset by peer - SSL_connect

Comment: Doh! Ok the problem was with my environment. Turns out I was behind a proxy server. *shakes tiny fist at heavens*